# Vim - Dotfiles - Vundle not recognized

Tags: plugin-vundle

So, I decided to manage my vimfiles (not dotfiles yet :P).  I copied `.vim` and `.vimrc` inside a `dotfiles` folder (and removed the `dot` from the filenames). I initialized `git` dir and pushed it to Github.  When I pull the files from Github, i have issues running Vim.  It has trouble running `Vundle` commands (`vundle#start` and `vundle#end`, and all Plugin statements).  I started believing that it was a second loaded `.vimrc`, so running :version shows this:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"                                                                                                                                                         
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"                                                                                                                                                       
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"                                                                                                                                                       
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"                                                                                                                                                        
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

The 2nd user `vimrc` file doesn't exist physically, so i'm utterly confused.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you installed Vundle the usual way (`git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim ~/.vim/bundle/...`). When you initialized a Git repository on `.vim`, Vundle's directory will be seen as a [Git link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162672/2072269) instead of a [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). This complicates things, since there's no simple way to add the plugins as part of the overall repo. What you could do is:

1. remove the plugin directories from git, but not their actual contents:

   ```
   git rm --cached bundle/Vundle.vim
   ```
2. Re-add it as a submodule:

   ```
   git submodule add https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git bundle/Vundle.vim
   ```

Then commit your changes. Depending on where Vundle is keeping your other plugins, you might want to add them as submodules too.

If you look at your Github repository, you should find the Vundle directory looking like these:

[image]

These are plugins in my `~/.vim/bundle`, added as submodules by [my git vim repo](https://github.com/murukeshm/vimrc/tree/master/bundle). Note the revision numbers added to each.

You'll have to initialize and update the submodules for the actual Vundle code to appear:

```
git submodule init
# or
git submodule update --init
```

This can also be done at the time of cloning:

```
git clone https://github.com/my/vim/repo ~/.vim --recursive
```

Comment: and then? how do i proceed? how do i fetch the data from the submodules to my local folder?

Comment: @h1k3n O.o That's what those commands are for. `git submodule update --init` should clone the Vundle repository.

Comment: i feel lost.  let me revisit this in the afternoon when i cool my head as it has been a tough day here in Greece. Thnx though, it seems that this topic stepped in a black area for me in git (submodules) that i need to explore.

Comment: I used those commands but they show no output and at the end i have only the folders of each submodule (maybe they aren't submodules in my case after all?).  I think i have made a mistake in the initialization of the process.

Comment: @h1k3n Guess I was wrong - when you added the bundle directory, the plugin directories *didn't* become proper submodules, but only git links. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4162672/2072269. Essentially, in your original repo, do `git rm --cached` for the plugin directories, then re-add them as submodules.